# Error con MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

Solicito de su ayuda, el dia de hoy fui a abrir **MySQL Workbench** y al momento de conectarme a Local instance me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Xampp y la version de **MySQL Workbench** es 6.3, mi sistema operativo es Windows 7

Comment: prueba abriendo el administrador de tareas y en la pestaña de servicios trata de arrancar el servicio de mysql manualmente y después tratas de nuevo de trabajar con el workbench

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos tienes trabajando con XAMPP?

Comment: El gestor de base de datos que estoy utilizando es MySQL Workbench 6.3